# regex for extracting data between tags

Tags: php, regex

I am trying  to extract the letters along with / in the given data below.(I don't want the 's' in the years as well as -)

```
football soccer/basketball

1990s-1999s
```

I am using  `/\D[a-zA-Z].*/s` in `preg_match_all` function. It returns the letters and the numbers.(When testing in rubular.com the above expression works but in the PHP program it does not).

Answer (score 0):

```
# ^([\D]+)$
# 
# Options: case insensitive; ^ and $ match at line breaks
# 
# Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) «^»
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([\D]+)»
#    Match a single character that is not a digit 0..9 «[\D]+»
#       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
# Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) «$»

preg_match_all('/^([\D]+)$/im', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[0];
```

Comment: @PritamRao glad I could help. Please check it as the accepted answer :)